# is this a good use of Seq.cache, in F#

Tags: f#

I'm going through a mutable ConcurrentDictionary to remove old entries.

```
let private cache = ConcurrentDictionary<Instrument * DateTimeOffset, SmallSet>()
```

and since I can't remove entries while iterating through the keys, I was wondering if this would be a good use for Seq.cache:

```
let old = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(-1.)
cache.Keys
|> Seq.filter (fun x -> snd x <= old)
|> Seq.cache
|> Seq.iter (fun x -> cache.TryRemove x |> ignore)
```

I have never used Seq.cache, and I assume it creates a separation between the two loops. Am I understanding how it works correctly?

Comment: https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#cache

Comment: I have a feeling that this code will crush with `InvalidOperationException`. Personally I would've use `cache.Keys |> Array.ofSeq |> Array.filter (...) |> Array.iter (...)`. `Seq.cache` is going to allocate space for every key anyway, so it's better to use `Array.ofSeq` to avoid creation of temporary buffers

Comment: The cache sequence returned by `Seq.cache` is a wrapper around the underlying sequence that you pass to `Seq.cache`.  The wrapper guarantees that the underlying sequence is iterated exactly once, no matter how many times you iterate the cache.  But it's still lazy: it doesn't start iterating the underlying sequence until it starts being iterated itself.  The function you want here is `Seq.toList` or `Seq.toArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario you described I don't see any reason why you need to iterate the collection multiple times. You can just go over the KeyValuePairs inside the dictionary and analyze each KeyValuePair if it matches your condition or no.
So, something like this should do the job:

```
cache |> Seq.iter(function
                  | x when snd x.Key <= old -> cache.TryRemove(x.Key) |> ignore
                  | _ -> ())
```

Comment: What I do not understand here is how we can modify the collection while iterating through it? usually you can't modify what you're iterating over. What makes the F# implementation different?

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary is not specific to F# and it's mutable collection. This trick would not work with any immutable collection like F# list. ConcurrentDictionary implements IEnumerable, so you can iterate over it via Seq.Iter gaining access to element, which is KeyValuePair. And then you mutate ConcurrentDictionary removing the Key that matches condition.

Comment: If you loop over the mutable dictionary, in C#: foreach (var x in cache)..., you use IEnumerable and if you modify the collection during that time, you'll get an exception. F# is not iterating the same way?

Comment: In C# this works exactly the same way as in F#, check [the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UCrZy9) to see it yourself. I think this is not throwing exceptions due to special implementation of `GetEnumerator` that allows parallel reads and writes of ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: ah, you are right.. I kept the habit of not doing that with the non concurrent collection and didn't really think that this doesn't apply to the concurrent one!